# Can we force chrome to use v 1.0 of Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, charts

We are using google charts but it's showing the followimg error:

*"Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.Columnchart is not a constructor"*

I used the latest version of chrome and this error is only shown in chrome. If I use firefox it's working fine and it shows the following warning in firefox:

*"Attempting to load version '1' of Google Charts, but the previously loaded '1.0' will be used instead."*

I have tried to update the version of loader.js file with the help of following link:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs

But no luck. Can anybody knows that how can I force the chrome to use the latest version of google chart?

I have tried to add the 1.0 version in the script file but it still no work.

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.